# Duplicated in values of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have created three different cells in IB, one with a UIStepper, one with a Switch, and one with a TextField. When I am setting the value on one of the steppers, another stepper automatically gets the same value. Why is this? Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 16 || indexPath.row == 15) {
            cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextFieldCell"];
            if (cell == nil)
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TextFieldCell"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 17) {
            cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BoolCell"];
            DCRoundSwitch *roundSwitch = (DCRoundSwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            roundSwitch.onText = @"Yes";
            roundSwitch.offText = @"No";
        }
        else {
            cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StepperCell"];
        }
        UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        myLabel.text = [[_tableArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSLog(@"cell er nil");
            return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"StepperCell"];
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

It is only the second sections which has enough rows that it makes trouble for me. The UILabels shows correctly, but the steppers are connected somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing already existing StepperCells, which is good, but you need to set the correct values for everything within that cell when it gets reused.

Comment: All the initial values is 0, which is my preferred option. The problem is when I change one value, it also changes anotherone. There are 15 StepperCells btw.

Comment: In the code you provided you do not set it to 0 anywhere explicitly. Unless you ommited that part of code, cells get reused with old values.